# Why are there blank nodes/attributes when using LibXML Ruby?

Tags: ruby, libxml2

Using the Gem libxml-ruby, when we parse XML like so:

```
document = LibXML::XML::Parser.string( xmlData ).parse
for n in document.root.children
  # Do something
end
```

What we actually get is something like this:

```
root
-node empty
-node with data
-node empty
```

Same thing with attributes, there's a blank one padding between those we actually care about. What we end up needing to use is `:options => LibXML::XML::Parser::Options::NOBLANKS`

Why? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Not necessarily an answer, but need formatting.)

What does the XML look like?

This XML:

```xml
<baz>
  <plugh>ohai</plugh>
</baz>
```

may contain whitespace text nodes for the CR/LF and indentation between the `<baz>` and `<plugh>` opening tags, and the same for between the closing tags. This may or may not be significant whitespace depending on the nature of the XML. Structurally, it's different than:

```xml
<baz><plugh>ohai</plugh></baz>
```

Comment: Dave, your hunch was right! It seems the blank node is created if there is a space between the tags. `<a> <b/> </a>` gives me blank nodes but `<a><b/></a>` does not.

Comment: @GeorgeChen Yeah, the whitespace text nodes have caught me out as well.

Comment: PS: You can use `each_element()` to traverse only element children.